# OSX Security Framework NameAndPassword sample application

Tags: cocoa, macos, sfauthorizationpluginview

I am investigating security plugins using SFAuthorizationPluginView under Mac OSX and as a first step looking at the NameAndPassword sample application. The app builds OK but I cannot get it to authenticate. So does anyone have any experience of SFAuthorizationPluginView or any other examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [Debugging An Authorization Plug-In With Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2008/tn2108.html) help?

Comment: Hey, did you answer me when I asked the same question on the Cocoa-dev mailing list? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Patrick it's been a while, but apparently they still haven't fixed this. As I don't have a second Mac nearby, could you tell me how did you fix the NameAndPassword code so that it authenticates?